# Flutter, Accessing hidden method

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I don't know exactly after what I get this error but every after 3 second I get access hidden method error in my debug log. How can I examine which function do this access and why? Is it the real problem? Should I avoid from this?

```
 W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.sekspir.mood(25281): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Comment: It's only warnings, that won't break anything, you can safely ignore them

Comment: Ok but this is killing my log screen.How can I ignore in Intellij ?

Comment: Logcat supports regex filter. However, I don't know how to filter that using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from GitHub issue:

> The bad news is taking a cursory look seems to show that it's not a
> Flutter issue but a general Android issue with how Android protobufs
> are using hidden APIs.
>
> It's been fixed on Android 11 in
> https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/art/+/1294616/ but
> unfortunately is unlikely to be backported to older Android versions.
> A more likely scenario is plugins updating to newer transitive
> versions of protobufs. There isn't much we can do in Flutter. Using
> the IDE to hide those messages in the output is a reasonable
> workaround in the meantime such as #27095 (comment).
>
> Internal issue b/154851649. External protobuf issue
> protocolbuffers/protobuf#7337.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095

Just ignore it